# Quasi Fermi-Dirac excited carriers Abinit

Tags: abinit

I am doing a electron-hole pair calculation via adding Quasi Fermi-Dirac excited carriers in Abinit....My structure has only 57 atoms but after one week running...it didn't converge and failed...with the following  tags:

```
nband 500
ivalence 450
nqfd  0.1 # exciting 0.1 electrons per u.c.
occopt 9
```

Do you have any suggestions? Could you please guide me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: +1. Welcome to our community!

Comment: Could you add the output/log of your calculation?